# Некорректно работающее css свойство backface-visibility

Tags: javascript, css

https://codepen.io/Don2Quixote/full/wXdoRe

```js
var front = new Image();
front.src = "https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303976/74ac8/iHI_OdnNwCc.jpg";
front.width = 200;
front.height = 340;
var deg = 180;
document.querySelector("#card").appendChild(front);
document.querySelector("#card").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("#card").style.transform = `rotateY(${deg}deg)`;
  deg += 180;
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 170px);
  perspective: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 3s;
}

#front {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div id="back"></div>
  <div id="front"></div>
</div>
```

При клике на карточку она разворачивается на 180 градусов. `translateY(180deg)`. После разворота с фотографии на заднюю сторону - некоторое время видно отзеркаленное изображение фотографии. Однако, для каждой стороны карточки прописано свойство `backface-visibility: hidden`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: в файерфоксе работает отлично, а вот в webkit видно эту проблему

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я дал ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ошибку: `document.querySelector("#card").appendChild(front);`
Картинка, находящаяся в переменной `front` должна быть помещена в `div#front`, а я ее кладу в `div#card`.

Comment: по почему тогда работает в Лисе а в webkit видно  косяк ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а вот это уже разные способы обработки css правил разными браузерами. Но у меня ошибка была именно такая. После исправления - всё стало работать правильно.